# SQL- Remove symmetrical duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table called **rates** with four foreign keys and a decimal amount (primary key is understood). I am using MY-SQL database 5.6.17. I suspect that the data contains duplicate amounts for reverse combinations **point_id_2** and **point_id_2**. The other two foreign keys,**method_id** and **class_id** seem to be mirrored in the respective tuples which appear to have duplicate amounts. See the image below.

[image]

If you look at the foreign keys,point_id_1, point_id_2 and the amount this is what I mean by "symmetrical data".

Is it possible to track down all rows where point_id_1 and point_id_2 are interchanged and the amounts are the same?
This way I can then decide on which rows to remove.

Comment: What has the foreign keys to do with it? If you replace that term with the word column, maybe your post will make more sense?

Comment: You should first tell us, for each `point_id_1`, `point_id_2` group, which value you should select from the other columns, I mean for example the `MAX(amount)`, `MIN(amount)`, ... etc, the same for other columns you want to select like method_ID etc...

Comment: I want to see all rows where point_id_1, point_id_2 are interchanged as seen in the image. Then based on the results I can decide if there is lots of unnecessary duplicate data. Basically if a tuple contains point_id_1 as 1 and point_id_2 as 2 and then the opposite, I want to compare them to see if the amount is the same. If so, i can delete one. But with the other id's in the mix. I may have to delete 3 rows for every duplicate. Hope its a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to know if you have duplicates on the two `POINT_ID` fields for the same amount?  You just need a simple join on the fields you think are matching:

```
SELECT r1.*, r2.*
FROM
 rates r1 
 INNER JOIN rates r2
 ON r1.point_ID_1 = r2.point_ID_2 AND r1.point_ID_2 = r2.point_ID_1
WHERE
  r1.amount = r2.amount
```

Comment: thank you, I will give it a go and see what happens.